# How to communicate between two PCs on the same LAN?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, software-rec, lan, instant-messaging

Another user and I are on the same LAN and often wish to send each other URLs or several photos, or such. Is there a program or a feature that would allow us to communicate simply? like a local PC-to-PC IM?

Windows 7 (PC 1) to Windows XP (PC 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LAN Chat](http://www.fomine.com/lan-chat.html) is a LAN based IM client, very simple and private to a local network

Comment: Moreover, as far as I test, it is totally free without ads.

Answer (score 6):

If you were logged in to the same server you could use [talk](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_talk.htm). Otherwise I generally us AIM (or another IM client). A local implementation would be nice but then it depends on having that local connection. AIM (or another IM client) will work locally and remotely.